# After typing "apt-get update" terminal says Could not open lock file

Tags: command-line, apt, 19.10, vmware, vmware-workstation

i am a beginner in Ubuntu and currently using Ubuntu 19.10
in terminal i used

```
apt-get update
```

and this error showed up

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

how to solve this issue? i am using Ubuntu 19.10 on VMware Workstation 15 Pro and updated it at first lunch by using the "Software Update"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't run `apt-get update` as a simple user.
As said by the error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

To do this you need Admin rights

Instead use sudo to get admin rights

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem solved!!!